# Collect network operation data with logstash in Windows

Tags: networking, udp, logstash, netflow, packetbeat

I am trying to get network operation data from my localhost. I know packetbeat can do some of the jobs. However, I would like to collect data with logstash but my configuration didn't output anything. Is there anyone who can give me some suggestions?

```
input{
    udp{
        port => 9995
        codec => netflow{
            versions => [5]
        }
    }
}
output{
    stdout{codec=>rubydebug}
    elasticsearch{
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        hosts => "localhost"
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with that? And I have get some confusion here:

1. what will be the difference in using netflow input or udp input?
2. What port should I listen to with udp input?

Thanks in advance.